# What's the difference between てform+行くand てform+いる?

Tags: grammar, subsidiary-verbs

I know what both mean and are used for, but when I look at my reference materials, the former is often used to express the same thing as the latter. Are details to this that I'm not getting?

Comment: `when I look at my reference materials, the former is often itself to express the same thing as the latter` -- 例文をいくつか見せていただければ・・

Comment: One example I saw was 駅まで走っていきます being translated as "I'm running to the station" and 経済を勉強していきます being translated as "I study economics"

Comment: 「駅まで走っていきます」「経済を勉強していきます」は、 「駅まで走っています」「経済を勉強しています」と意味が違いますね。。。

Comment: Roy, the 「て」 in 「走っていきます」 is equivalent to "by", as in the method you will use to achieve something. On the otherhand, the 「て」 in 「勉強していきます」 is as I explained in my answer. Confusing, eh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I will assume by 「ていく」 you do not mean "Do something and leave".*

When you are 「ている」, you are doing it now. No reference to the future.

When you will 「ていく」, you will do it from now, from this point on.

So,

> 1. 「ていく」implies continued effort, where as 「ている」 is only about what you are doing now.
> 2. 「ていく」doesn't necessarily imply that you weren't doing it before. It depends on the context.
>      (i.e.「これからも引き続き工場の安全を確保するために全力を尽くし**て行き**たいと思っております。」= "We will continue to
>      work hard to maintain safety at our factories.")